# Preventing DOS_OUTLOOK_TO_MX SpamAssasin's flag

Tags: amazon-ec2, smtp, phpmailer, spam-prevention, spamassassin

I have an application hosted in an Amazon EC2 Server that uses e-mail service from a shared web host. I did this to utilize the shared hosting e-mail server and the available e-mail administration tool and webmail interface.

My application uses **amazon SES to send e-mail**. I just authorized SES to send mails with my domain name (by adding some entries to my dns records and confirming  I'm the domain owner), and this is working ok. When I need to send a mail, I connect to SES SMTP server and send it **using PHPMailer**.

Everything is working ok, except **my mails are getting the DOS_OUTLOOK_TO_MX flag** in SpamAsssasin's, making it sometimes be classified as spam.

What this flag means? Is there some way to avoid it?

Comment: have you set proper MX records in your domain settings?

Comment: Yes, I have! There is another flag for sending emails from a not authorized server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spamassassin **DOS_OUTLOOK_TO_MX** rule is fired when two internal flags are set by processed message: **__DOS_DIRECT_TO_MX** and **__ANY_OUTLOOK_MUA**.

**__DOS_DIRECT_TO_MX** flag means that the message was sent directly from sender email client to recipient MTA server. This is usually true for internal mail but can occur in your case when a recipient also uses Amazon SES for mail processing.

**__ANY_OUTLOOK_MUA** flag means that the message has `X-Mailer =~ /^Microsoft (?:Office )?Outlook\b/` header.

Both internal flags are harmless by themselves but their combination leads to DOS_OUTLOOK_TO_MX with high spam score. You need to check X-Mailer header of messages sent with PHPMailer. This header should be set to *PHPMailer*, not to *Microsoft Outlook* or something similar.